# How to send REST request with build parameters in Jenkins Post Build Actions?

Tags: rest, groovy, jenkins

I am working on a CI system with Jenkins. But now I got a problem. I need to do the following steps.

1:Jenkins build

2:Deploy to Tomcat

3:find a way to send the build parameters (Job Name, build number...) to a web server (I am using REST now).

4:Web Server trigger testing system.

5:Jenkins get the result from testing system.

6:update build status

7:send emails.

I have problem with the step 3. I need to send those info after the deploy. I am thinking a way as following.

write those parameters to a file during build step, then call a script or Java problem to process the file and send out those info by REST.

But that is ugly. Is there any better ways to do it?

Side questions

Can groovy do this?

How to import groovy http-builder library to Jenkins?

Comment: I found a walk around solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a walk around solution.

1: ran echo command during the build to get the build ID and print to log.

2:wrote a small Java program to get the JSON response of the build then sent the necessary info as rest request to the server you set. The program is like a message forwarder.

3:in post build actions, use groovy post build to fetch the log then call the Java program.